# Time to empty a pressurize oxygen tank through a regulator

Tags: fluid-mechanics

## Time to empty a pressurize oxygen tank through a regulator.

The tank contain 12oz of oxygene at 3000psi (room temp.)

The regulator is set to 120psi.

The exit pipe is a 14inch pipe with 2mm inner diameter.

The experiment stop when the tank reach 120psi.

#### I may change the tank size and the regulator output pressure.

Comment: I have no real physic base but my intuition is that there should be a equation that give the amount of gaz per time that will flow through the 2mm hose from a 120psi environment to the 14.7psi of the atmosphere.

Comment: any limit to the flow rate?

Comment: Not that I know.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/408932/pressurized-tank-emptying-over-time-through-a-given-area

Comment: I did saw that post but that doesn't include pressure regulator.
I actually think my case is simpler, since I basically want to know the flow out of the exit 2mm pipe from a constant source of 120psi.

Comment: The only thing you need to do is to set the new pressure in your case it is 120 psi  (in integral) in the last step.

Comment: What is the pressure at the exit.? Is it left to the atmosphere simply? if yes what is the ambient pressure and temperature at your locality ?